# qooxdoo virtual tree as menu

Tags: menu, tree, virtual, qooxdoo

I have a function, which creates layout with widgets. The problem is what one of the widget is virtual tree (on left side of layout) and the second widget on the right side depends on clicked row on left side. Virtual tree works like menu, which should return value of row name to the right widget and recreate it on right side with provided data. However currently it is not recreating, but adding a new widget to the old one. How to recreate widget on the right side not adding it to the existing one (interface is similar to qooxdoo demobrowser view with tests)?

```
_createLayout : function()
    {
        // Create main layout
        var dockLayout = new qx.ui.layout.Dock();
        var dockLayoutComposite = new qx.ui.container.Composite(dockLayout);
        this.getRoot().add(dockLayoutComposite, {edge:0});

        // Create header
        this.__header = new bank.view.Header(); 
        dockLayoutComposite.add(this.__header, {edge: "north"});

        // Create toolbar
        this.__toolBarView = new bank.view.ToolBar(this);
        dockLayoutComposite.add(this.__toolBarView, {edge: "north"});

        // Create the tree view, which should create dockLayout below, when user clicks with Row value
        dockLayoutComposite.add(this.getTreeView(), {edge: "west"});
        // This layout should be created and recreated with clicked row value
    dockLayoutComposite.add(bank.InvoiceListBuilder.createList("Tree_returned_value"), {edge: "center"});
    },

getTreeView : function()
    {
        var hBox = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox(20));
        var tree = new qx.ui.treevirtual.TreeVirtual("Tree");
        tree.setColumnWidth(0, 170);
        tree.setAlwaysShowOpenCloseSymbol(true);
        var dataModel = tree.getDataModel();
        var te2 = dataModel.addBranch(null, "Folders", true);
        dataModel.addBranch(te2, "Incoming", false);
        dataModel.addBranch(te2, "Outgoing", false);
        dataModel.addBranch(te2, "Drafts", false);
        dataModel.setData();
        hBox.add(tree);
        var foldercontent = bank.InvoiceListBuilder.createList("incoming");
        tree.addListener("changeSelection",
           function(e)
           {
            // this function should return row value to function: bank.InvoiceListBuilder.createList("Tree_returned_value") and create/recreate dockLayout with newly created widget from bank.InvoiceListBuilder.createList function
           });
        return hBox;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using a old virtual tree implementation (qx.ui.treevirtual.TreeVirtual), I would suggest to use the qx.ui.tree.VirtualTree implementation.

The next step is to use something like a controller for your view, which listen to the selection and creates widgets when the selection changed. The controller should know the container for adding widgets.

When your left side is just a list. You can also use the virtual list (qx.ui.list.List) and use a set of the tree model.

Cheers,
Chris